# I have an error when i trying to run my maven project: Failed execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli)

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml, maven-exec-plugin

I have this problem when i trying to run my project.

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project projectName: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

I am using Netbeans and I'm working with a maven's project, my pom.xml looks like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/exec-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectName\src\main\java\com\company\projectName\Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I've tried several things but I can't solve the problem, anyone could help me?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I had a problem with another line in my code. 
Thanks ! :)

Comment: maybe delete this question then. poeple come here to find nothing.or at least specify what caused the problem